# Chrome Driver and version Chrome version83

Tags: python, google-chrome, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have been trying to scrape some information for google when I have got this error:

```
SessionNotCreatedException: Message: session not created: This version of ChromeDriver only supports Chrome version 80
```

I would have two questions:

- is there any chance to have a new version of driver = webdriver.Chrome that can work with this new version?

and/or

- is there any chance to downgrade Google Chrome?

This is the module that I am currently using:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome('path/chromedriver')
driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this issue appears because there is an inconsistency between versions of chrome and ChromeDriver. 
First thing I suggest is checking your chrome version by going to Help -> About Google Chrome and check the version. So let's say it's 83.something

[image]

Then download the Chrome Webdriver with the appropriate version here [Download ChromeDriver](https://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) and you should be good to go.

Hope this helped!